# Inject HTML into Grid FrontPage

Tags: html, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm new to Umbraco and recently discovered the `Grid FrontPage` ContentType where you can dynamically design a whole page, which is very convenient in many ways. However, it seems to be limited when it comes to adding custom HTML content, in my case I want to add an iframe containing google maps:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=example&key=example"></iframe>
```

Now my question is:

- how can I inject HTML Markup into the `Grid FrontPage`?
- if it's not possible, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to go to "Developer"->"Data Types"->"Grid Frontpage". Select the "Row configuration" that you want to have the code on. On the right bottom there is a checkbox that says "Code".